# How to use concat in an update query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have the following query:

```
$sql = "update zzz_users set password = "'".$encrypted."' where username = '".$email."'";
CustomQuery($sql);
```

And I just cannot get the concat right, could someone please show me how to do it

Comment: Cant see where are you using concat?

Answer (score 0):

The correct query is:

```
$sql = "update zzz_users set password = '" . $encrypted . "' where username = '" . $email . "'";
```

Comment: Correct query doesn't have this `'" . $encrypted . "'`, instead of that it should be prepared query.

Comment: @VeeeneX: question is about PHP syntax, we don't know what `CustomQuery` function do and what is in variables. In `$ecnrypted` can be escaped and hashed password, then everything will be okay.

Comment: Never trust user functions, never.

Comment: @VeeeneX: if `$encrypted` is defined above, everything is okay. And the function, has only one parameter, so it expects SQL query, nothing else. It's replacement for `mysqli_query`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot more wrong here than not getting the concatenation right.

First of all, if you're just trying to put variables into a string in PHP, consider using double quotes and putting the variables directly into the string:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `zzz_users` SET `password` = $encrypted WHERE `username` = $email";
```

There's no need for all the starting and stopping of strings in that case.

However, what you're doing here is extremely dangerous because of [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should **DEFINITELY NOT** be putting variables directly into your SQL commands.

The best way to do this is to use a library that knows how to accept formatting strings and create safe `SQL` for you. For example, something like [MeerkoDB](http://www.meekro.com/) will let you write this `SQL` statement like this:

```
DB::query("UPDATE `zzz_users` SET `password`=%s WHERE `username`=%s", $encrypted, $email);
```

This is actually safe, because it will ensure that the SQL is properly escaped, preventing SQL injection attacks. Of course, you can roll your own escaping, but it's almost always a better idea to use a well-established library (there are many free/open source and commercial/proprietary offering out there).

Answer (score -1):

There is an `"` too much after `password =`. You should escape the strings before writing it to the database, otherwise you may get a possible SQL injection issue.

```
$sql = "update zzz_users set password = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($encrypted). "' where username = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($email). "'";
CustomQuery($sql);
```

Comment: Passowrd has to be hashed, `_real_escape_string` isn't correct way (it' s maybe hashed in this var, we don't know). `Mysql` extension is deprecated.